# Discussions or conversations?

Tags: discussion, tags

This site has two tags -- [conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations) and [discussions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussions) -- that have very similar definitions and that are being used in exactly the same way. Could these be synonymised please?

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again, tagging on this site is a mess. If anyone wants to go looking for stuff to fix, you'll find a lot of stuff.

Comment: I think the two are different? You can have a conversation without discussing anything?

Comment: Or are they just used for the same types of questions, and thus in a wrong manner?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell "You can have a conversation without discussing anything?" what? "Or are they just used for the same types of questions" yes, of course they are.

Comment: then, I believe we should clear them up. I'll dive into it later tonight. What I meant to say was that discussion implies a certain disagreement between speakers and arguments pro and con begin exchanged (nice weather huh? No, it's not --> discussion follows) , while a conversation may also be done in agreement (nice weather huh? Yes, are you going to do anything outdoors because it is so nice? --> No discussion, but conversation). So they are 2 different things for me, but if they are used for the same purpose, they are clearly not 2 things here. 
1/2

Comment: And excuse the 2 comments, I was too late to edit the first one.  2/2

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I don't think discussion implies disagreement.  For that matter, conversation doesn't imply agreement.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Might just be the language then. A discussion and a conversation translate to two very different things in Dutch, with the discussion implying disagreement... I've looked up some dictonaries, and I think I can agree :)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell thanks for clarifying; I didn't realize it was a translation issue.  (I'm always impressed by people who manage to learn English as a second language; we sure don't make it easy.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ah well, it's just that sometimes, I need to look a little further than google translate, and also search for definitions ;) And btw, English was the easiest of the foreign languages I had to learn in school (We also had French and German)

Comment: If a conversation is about nothing in particular or free-ranging quickly from topic to topic it would be called small-talk or chat rather than a 'discussion' which implies more detailed conversation focused on some topic, so I think you are right to say *you can have a conversation without it being a discussion*, @tinkeringbell. On the other hand, you cannot have a discussion without having a conversation, except by posting whole letters and other outdated methods.

Answer (score 2):

[conversations](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversations) has 126 questions and a tag wiki.  [discussions](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussions) has 4 questions and no wiki.  I just proposed discussions as a synonym of conversations; if there's a difference, it's not clear from the affected questions.

People with more than 1250 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag can vote on [the proposal](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/tags/conversations/synonyms).

Comment: Well then, you've got my upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, they don't *always* mean the same thing, but then again, not everyone knows the distinction.

In M-W's simplest definitions, a **conversation[¹](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conversation)** is just a talk between two or more people, while a **discussion[²](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discussion)** is a conversation for the purpose of understanding or debating a question or subject.

I've not currently gone through the tagged questions to see whether these tags are used incorrectly, but I'd say that ***if*** we're going to keep the two tags separate, then let's use *discussions* for questions where there is an aim to convince someone else, and *conversations* for other casual conversations.

(Just to be clear: I'm not proposing we keep the two tags, and I'm not proposing we remove one either. My answer was in response to the initial revision of your question in which you asserted that the two words mean exactly the same thing.)

Comment: Why not use a tag, such as debate, where it's crystal clear that the tag should be used in cases where there's disagreement?

Comment: @Hamlet why are you asking me that? Looks like a question for another meta.

Comment: Because you are proposing that we keep discussions, even though it's being used in exactly the same way as conversations. If you want to create a new tag, make the name something that makes the tag's usage crystal clear.

Comment: @Hamlet I think you didn't see my point. I'm not _proposing_ we keep the two. Please read it again.

Comment: @Hamlet Worth noting, not every discussion is a debate either. So I'm not sure if having a "debate" tag would make it "crystal clear".

Comment: My 2 cents: Since the tag wiki for conversations includes the following sentence "Also how to avoid/discuss certain topics in conversations", we don't need a tag for discussions or debate. If we really want one, it should be about debating-techniques or something.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell that is some two cents worth posting in an answer box so that users can vote up or down, not as a comment under mine. :)

Comment: @NVZ The proposal is already accepted. I'll wait and see, and if I think we really miss a tag for that, I'll make another meta :)